# Is there a way to get ordinal index of a pod with in kubernetes statefulset configuration file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, statefulset

We are on Kubernetes 1.9.0 and wonder if there is way to access an "ordinal index" of a pod with in its statefulset configuration file. We like to dynamically assign a value (that's derived from the ordinal index) to the pod's label and later use it for setting pod affinity (or antiaffinity) under spec.

Alternatively, is the pod's instance name available with in statefulset configfile? If so, we can hopefully extract ordinal index from it and dynamically assign to a label (for later use for affinity).

Comment: There's a thread about this as a feature request here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40651

And one that _may_ apply to you: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40651#issuecomment-307164995

NOTE: I know _nothing_ of kubernetes

Comment: What do you mean by "*... under spec.*"?

Answer (score 17):

[Right now](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30427) the only option is to extract index from host name

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export INDEX=${HOSTNAME##*-}"]
```

Comment: Not a correct workaround if the env variable must be set before the entry point is called: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/ *There is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT*

Comment: how would one use the exported INDEX then in the args?

Answer (score 14):

You could essentially get the unique name of your pod in statefulset as an environment variable, you have to extract the ordinal index from it though

In container's spec:

```
env:
  - name: cluster.name
    value: k8s-logs
  - name: node.name
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Comment: Question asked for **ordinal**, not whole name.

Answer (score 5):

To get the exact ordinal number of a statefulset you can use the following code

```
env:
  - name: ORDINAL_NUMBER
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.labels['apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index']
```

Comment: It gets the job done for version 1.28.0+. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#apps-kubernetes.io-pod-index