# getting count of pods in a StatefulSet at runtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Is there a way to get the replica count at runtime within a pod that belongs to a StatefulSet?
I have verified that the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306021/5514015 gives you the hostname of the pod, which includes the pod ordinal number, at runtime, but I would also like to know the number of replicas configured in the StatefulSet. Is this possible to determine?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the number of replicas is not available through the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api). But in a `StatefulSet`, as you say, it is common to need this number.

Proposed ways to get the number:

- Implement this within your app so that they coordinate, and perhaps can find out it through *ordinal* identities.
- Alternatively let your app communicate with the Kubernetes API Server using e.g. [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go), but this ties your application to Kubernetes.

For reliability, you might want to design your app in a way so that it can work (at least for some time) without the Kubernetes control-plane being available, so I would recommend to implement this without the Kubernetes API e.g. the first solution above.