# How can I run export in postStart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm using StatefulSet in kubernetes, and need to get ordinal index of pod.
I tried to export in `postStart.exec.command`, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code I tried.

```yaml
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export INDEX=${POD_NAME##*-}"]
```

How can I export ordinal index?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [GitLink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40651#issuecomment-350810183) and [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50751423/19230181) use postStart.exec.command as below and give a try.

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export INDEX=${HOSTNAME##*-}"]
```

Refer to this [Gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40651) and [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#examining-the-pod-s-ordinal-index) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
But I can't see that env inside pod because export ran in another context.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable based on the POD name, for example:

```
env:
 - name: POD_NAME
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: metadata.name
```

And then, in the post start lifecycle, use TR command to create your ordinary number, example:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: 
         - /bin/bash
         - -ec
         - export INDEX=$(echo $POD_NAME|tr -dc '0-9')
```